# Windows Service how to slow down infinite loop

Tags: c#, service

The way I was told to make windows services is as followed:

```
Thread serviceThread = new Thread(new Thread(runProc())
Boolean isRunning = true;

if (_isRunning)
   {
      serviceThread.Start();
   }else
      close and log service

void runProc()
{
   while(_isRunning)
   {
      //Service tasks
   }

   _isRunning = false;
}
```

This has worked fine for me so far but now I need to make a service that has big breaks in it, up to 2 hours at a time. Also I have started using timers so nothing is being done in the infinite loop other than stopping runProc() running over and over again which I can imagine is bad because threads are being made and remade a lot.

My question is, I have read that it is bad practice to put Thread.Sleep(big number) in that while(_isRunning) infinite loop, is this true? If this is the case, how do I get around the loop running constantly and using loads of resource? There is literally nothing being done in the loop right now, it is all handled in the tickevent of my timer,  the only reason I have a loop is to stop runProc ending.

Thanks a lot an sorry if I explain myself badly

Comment: Is that `runProc` only method to set `_isRunning` to false? If yes this is infinite loop

Comment: Where to you see indications that Thread.Sleep(big number) in that loop is bad practice?

Comment: Hey BlueMonk, something about it causing different things to stop and also it not being accurate?

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Sleep` is bad because it cannot be (easily) interrupted<sup>1</sup>.

I generally prefer to use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) or similar:

```
class abc {
  Thread serviceThread = new Thread(new Thread(runProc())
  ManualResetEvent abort = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  void Start(){
      serviceThread.Start();
  }
  void Stop(){
     abort.Set();
     serviceThread.Join();
  }
  void runProc()
  {
     while(!abort.WaitOne(delay))
     {
      //Service tasks
     }
  }
}
```

Hopefully you get the gist, not a great code sample.

The `delay` can be as large or small as you want (and can be arbitrarily recomputed during each loop). The `WaitOne` call will either delay the progress of this thread for `delay` milliseconds or, if `Stop` is called, will cause the loop to exit immediately.

---

<sup>1</sup>To summarize my position from the comments below - it can only be interrupted by blunt tools like `Thread.Abort` or `Thread.Interrupt` which both share the failing (to a greater or lesser extent) that they can also introduce their associated exceptions at various *other* places in your code. If you can *guarantee* that the thread is actually inside the `Thread.Sleep` call then the latter may be okay - but if you can make such a guarantee, you can also usually arrange to use a less blunt inter-thread communication mechanism - such as the one I've suggested in this answer.

Comment: I've never had problems waking threads with an ``Interrupt()`` call. The interrupted thread just needs to catch the appropriate exception and exit its main loop.

Comment: @acfrancis - it's less dangerous than `Thread.Abort`, but not by much in my view - note that you've got no idea *what* specifically has caused the thread to enter the **WaitSleepJoin** state - among other things, it may be waiting for a lock - well, you better have architected your code to grab *all* locks before it perturbs any shared state or you may have issues.

Comment: I have a feeling we write very different code in our services. If one of my threads gets interrupted, it'll either quit (if the service's stopping) or catch the exception, log it and iterate the loop again to perform the next unit of work available. That's always worked well for me.

Comment: @acfrancis - my issue is that `Thread.Sleep` isn't the *only* place where the `ThreadInterruptedException` might suddenly get thrown - I'd rather use a reliable form of inter-thread communication where I indicate "at *this* piece of code, I'll respond to a *specific* signal (or set of signals)"

Answer (score 0):

I've always written services with a main infinite loop, not timers. Inside the loop, I check to see if there's any work to do, if so I do the work, if not I call `Thread.Sleep()`. That means that as long as there's work to be done, the loop will keep iterating, running as fast as it can. When the queue of work "dries up", it sleeps a little (a few seconds or minutes) while more work becomes available.

That's always worked really well for back-end jobs on a server where there's a constant stream of new work to be done throughout the day (and night). If you have big periods with no work the service will wake many times to check and then go back to sleep. You might like that or not. As long as the check is quick, it shouldn't be an issue. An alternative is to use a scheduled task (or database job) so that you know that work will be completed at specific times throughout the day. That's a better approach in some cases.

Comment: This is how I have designed all my previous services but it just seems like an overkill for a service that I know only has to check every 1h45m. I am currently looking into scheduled tasks, so thanks for that!

Comment: Agreed, I would consider a scheduled task in that case. But, of course, the devil is in the details.